# separate a string in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, jsp

I am facing difficulty in separating the following line

```
  String a= request.getParameter("fruits");
```

I am getting output as **OrangeAppleMangoBanana** 
I am trying to split this output as following:

```
Orange
Apple
Mango
Banana
```

I am applying following code but getting no result. Please guide me

```
  String[] arrSplit = a.split("");
 for (int i=0; i < arrSplit.length; i++)
 {
  out.println(arrSplit[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Currently you're not doing any splitting on commas in the code you're showing. Please provide a [mcve], as at the moment your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Show us the code that does not work.

Comment: There is still no relevant code in your question?!

Comment: I have added the code I had used, its not working pls help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want to split the string before a capital letter and after a small letter. You can use this regex:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

Looks behind for a small letter, and looks ahead for a capital letter.

You can pass it to `split` like this:

```
String[] splitString = a.split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])");
```

And print it out:

```
for (String fruit : splitString) {
    System.out.println(fruit);
}
```

Comment: I *love* smart answers to malformed questions! Thanks!

Comment: I have a doubt suppose I have to show it in vertical way like I have displayed in my question how can I do it pls help me

Comment: @Tom where do you want to show it? If it’s in a console then my current code would do that. If it’s in a JSP page then you should search online for how to do that. I don’t know JSP.

Comment: @Sweeper Hi Actually I want to show it in JSP page , anyways I am trying. Pls help me little bit by upvoting my question as its not that bad.

Comment: @Tom Psst, asking for up-votes usually brings opposite effect (strangely asking for down-votes work).

Comment: @Tom Anyway JSP is responsible for providing *view* which is HTML code, so use proper HTML way to show data in separate lines. Depending on what that data is you can use lists or separate paragraphs, or many other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Just another example with another regex:

```
String input = "OrangeAppleMangoBanana";
String[] fruits = input.split("(?=\\p{Upper})");
for (String fruit : fruits) {
   System.out.println(fruit);
}
```